# "Unexpected Identifier" when passing object resulting from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am rolling my own typeahead implementation using an input box tied to a select2 plugin.  The user will enter either a manual email address, which will then be validated with the onchange event against an email regex, or they can begin typing the DisplayName of recipients already tied to their account.  This list will be fetched via an ajax call to the controller, which then makes a service call and retrieves the data, which is then through listitems created dynamically.  If the user clicks or taps on one of the DisplayNames that are displayed, that recipient will then be added to the list of selected recipients and displayed in the select2 from that point on.

The typeahead and ajax calls are working correctly and the data is being returned and displayed correctly; however, I cannot seem to pass the object returned from the inital ajax call as a parameter to a function.  If I try and pass the raw value, I get an `'unexpected identifier'` error in my console debugger; if I try and pass in `JSON.stringify(value)`, I get `'unexpected token ;.'`  I can always fall back by passing in the ID property of the recipient (this works fine, it's when I try and pass complex objects that I run into difficulty) and rebuilding the object again, but it would obviously be preferable to avoid this and avoid making another service call.  Thanks in advance.

Here is the script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#selectedRecipientList").select2({ tags: null, tokenSeparators: [",", " "] });
            $('.select2-input').keyup(function (e) {                    
                var currentString = $('.select2-input').val();
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '@Url.Action("RecipientTypeAhead", "RecipientManager")',
                    data: { query: currentString },
                    success: (function (data) {
                        $('#TypeAheadRecipientsList').empty();
                        $(data).each(function (index, value) {
                            $('#TypeAheadRecipientsList').append('<li onclick="AddRecipientFromPicker(' + JSON.stringify(value) + ')">' + value.DisplayName + '</li>');
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        });

function AddRecipientFromPicker(someData){} //only ever reaches here if int primitive is passed in
```

Here is an example of what the objects look like after they are returned in the ajax method:                     `{"AccountName":"abc","DisplayName":"abc","Email":"abc@test.net","Id":94654}`

Comment: Please don't use inline event handlers. jQuery provides much cleaner ways to do that using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do:

```
$(data).each(function (index, value) {
    $('#TypeAheadRecipientsList').append('<li onclick="AddRecipientFromPicker(' + JSON.stringify(value) + ')">' + value.DisplayName + '</li>');
});
```

since `data` is not a dom element.

Try doing this instead:

```
for(var index in data) {
   var value = data[index];
   $('#TypeAheadRecipientsList').append('<li onclick="AddRecipientFromPicker(' + JSON.stringify(value) + ')">' + value.DisplayName + '</li>');
}
```

**Also** please try not to use inline event handlers.

***So*** to put it all together:

```
for(var index in data) {
   var value = data[index];
   var listItem = $('<li>' + value.DisplayName + '</li>');
   listItem.data('value', JSON.stringify(value)).on('click', function(){
       AddRecipientFromPicker($(this).data('value'));
   });
   $('#TypeAheadRecipientsList').append(listItem);
}
```

Comment: @DCoder I am pretty sure. as per the OP every `value` contains something that looks like `{"AccountName":"abc","DisplayName":"abc","Email":"abc@test.net","Id":94654}` and the click event is completely scoped.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you so much!  Will accept as soon as SO cooldown period is done.

Thanks for the tip on coding style as well, much obliged.

Comment: Since all click handlers are bound in the same scope, they all capture the same `value` variable. http://jsfiddle.net/aSTLq/

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this as well, it's always passing in the value of the last object to the function.

Comment: looks like it's working perfectly now, thanks again to both of you for all the help

Comment: @gutsmania i updated it once more so the stringify doesn't happen on every click.